# Response.Redirect stopped working with IIS 7 rewrite rules

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I have recently migrated a web site over to a new server running Windows Server 2008 and subsequently being hosted on IIS 7.

I have implemented URL rewrite rules for pages. Here is an example.

```
               <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL58" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(shop)/(item)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="shopitem.aspx?{R:1}&amp;{R:2}&amp;id={R:3}&amp;cat={R:4}&amp;title={R:5}" />
               </rule>
```

The URL should look something like this. http://www.website.com/shop/item/10/products/table/

The page works fine except when I'm clicking on a Button and running this event.

```
protected void btnAddToBasket_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Response.Redirect("~/shoppingbasket/");
}
```

The outcome of the Redirect seems to be Redirecting on itself and the URL then changes to: http://www.website.com/shop/item/10/products/table/?shop&item&id=10&cat=products&title=table

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've done a few searches for this and I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Have you tried to use the [Failed Request Tracing tool](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to see what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered this question by using the following tutorial [here](http://blogs.iis.net/ruslany/archive/2008/10/23/asp-net-postbacks-and-url-rewriting.aspx).

I put the following code at the top of Page_Load event.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL"])) 
{ 
     Form.Action = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL"]; 
}
```

and the page is now working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's actually "oh shoot, I missed it!" types of issues that we all have :).

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="shopitem.aspx?{R:1}&amp;{R:2}&amp;id={R:3}&amp;cat={R:4}&amp;title={R:5}" />
```

You are specifically calling a Rewrite.  Change it to Redirect and I'm sure it'll perform as you expect.

It's worth noting that using a redirect in an event AND a rewrite in conjunction is probably conflicting in IIS.  You might want to choose one or the other.